# XML and perl parsing using DOM - Searching for a value

Tags: xml, perl, dom

Im using following script to count the number of elements in a xml file. 
Thanks to one of the gurus here I can print the number.

Just want to know how do I add another funcionality which will look for the word "web" and print only the number of units which contains that word?

Thanks.

```
  #!/usr/bin/perl -w 
  use strict;
  use XML::DOM; 

  my $course_file= shift;

  my $parser = new XML::DOM::Parser;

  my $course = $parser->parsefile($course_file); 

  my @units = $course->getElementsByTagName("title");


  foreach my $u (@units)
  {
    foreach my $child ($u->getChildNodes)
    {

        if ($child->getNodeName eq "internet")
        {
            $u->removeChild($child);
        }
    } 
   }

   print(scalar(@units),"\n");
```

Example XML:

```
<course>
  <name>Internet Computing</name>
  <duration>3 years</duration>
  <unit>
    <title>Programming</title>
    <lecturer>
      <surname language="English">X</surname>
    </lecturer>
  </unit>
  <unit>
    <title>Internet</title>
    <lecturer>
      <surname>S</surname>
    </lecturer>
  </unit>
</course>
```

Comment: The input file doesn't seem to have the word "web".

Comment: Sorry couldnt find a place to edit the question. just assume it has word web instead of programming in the title.

Comment: At the bottom of your question, on the line below the list of tags, are four options: `share`, `edit`, `close`, and `flag`. One of those is the one you want

Answer (score 2):

The XML::DOM module is not really a module I'd recommend since it doesn't support XPath and it's not very fast.  For the type of thing you're trying to do, I'd recommend a module that support XPath.  The two most commonly used ones are XML::LibXML and XML::Twig.

I've written a [tutorial for using XML::LibXML](http://grantm.github.io/perl-libxml-by-example/) which includes lots of examples.

For your question the following might do what you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML;

my $course_file= shift;

my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => $course_file);

my @matches = $dom->findnodes('//unit[contains(./title, "Programming")]');
my $count = @matches;

say "Total matching units: $count";
```

You can learn more about XPath with the [examples page](http://grantm.github.io/perl-libxml-by-example/xpath.html), which also links to the [XPath sandbox](http://grantm.github.io/perl-libxml-by-example/_static/xpath-sandbox/xpath-sandbox.html?q=%2F%2Fmovie%2Ftitle) where you can try different expressions to see what they match.